# What to do with old answers that provide buggy code?

Tags: support, old-answers

My flag was rejected:

Code provided is buggy. – G. Samaras yesterday   declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer.

I think that answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5842442/2411320) pollute SO. What to do, if flag is not my weapon against them?

Comment: just downvote, it is a legal answer, nothing to flag.

Comment: But shouldn't the answer be removed? Even if I downvote it seems that the author of it is idle now (he didn't respond to my answer).

Comment: No, it was his answer, I can't judge how bad it is, since I'm not on C.

Comment: The edit I made was not correcting his code @bummi, just a formatting, nothing nothing more. He had `# include` and I made it `#include`, that's all! Well I run his code and it didn't work as I explain at my comment there. The people that know some C can check that this doesn't work. So your point is that regardless of the fact that this answer is way wrong it should be there "forever" in case the author remains idle "forever"?

Comment: You can't expect 17 people to be able to judge the technical accuracy of each and every one of the site's answers. Incorrect answers should be handled by the community, use your down and delete votes.

Comment: it doesnt "pollute" SO; its is one of several answers and not accepted or upvoted. your comment is a warning to others that it may be faulty.  May be related: http://xkcd.com/386/

Comment: Sorry, did not inspect deep enough, your edit was ok, sorry :), but the answer is an answer.

Comment: @Yannis my delete votes are not the flags? Because that's what I did and got rejected. I don't expect 17 people to do this, I expect that the flagging system (for example) can take care of them too, after more approval votes. So what I get from the comments is that we downvote or/and write a comment and nothing more. Nice link from Plutonix.

Comment: @Yannis why should it be deleted if it is a trying to answer the question and not just a link only answer? Downvoting and adding comments are the method of choice.

Comment: A DV is the strongest signal you could send.  It tells others that it is so bad that you spent some of your rep to warn them.  There is a difference between crap answers, bad answers and wrong answers.

Comment: @G.Samaras Flags aren't votes, you are calling a moderator for help. You'll be able to vote to delete once you earn 10K rep. Until then, downvoting and (if you are feeling charitable) commenting are your main weapons against incorrect answers.

Comment: Comments are better, since they allow you to keep up with any changes the author mades (as soon as (s)he notifies you), but they require more effort than the downvote. Thanks @Yannis.